# Uninstalled my app. And when reinstalled app values don't change

Tags: android

My application is a tycoon game in which the user taps a button in order to increase his score and so he buys upgrades to increase the amount of score he has quickly.

Well, just out of curiosity I uninstalled my app and the reinstalled it through Android Studio, when I ran it the app didn't work. I tried tapping the button to increase the score, but still it didn't increase. To save the users score I use **SharedPreferences** after they close the app. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon.R.id.textView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageButton myButton;
private int Counter;
private ImageButton autoclick;
private TextView myTextView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int add;
private TextView myAddView;
private ImageButton singleclick;
private int Singleadd = 1;
private ImageButton money;
private boolean[] array;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("Count")) {
            Counter = bundle.getInt("Count");
        }
        if (bundle.containsKey("Add")) {
            add = bundle.getInt("Add");
        }
        if (bundle.containsKey("Single")) {
            Singleadd = bundle.getInt("Single");
        }
        if (bundle.containsKey("array")) {
            array = bundle.getBooleanArray("array");
        }
    }
    add = getaddvalue();
    Counter = getvalue();
    Singleadd = getSinglevalue();

    money = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    autoclick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.autoclick);
    singleclick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.singleclick);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(textView);
    myAddView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Counter = ButtonCounter(Counter);
        }
    });
    autoclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
            intent.putExtra("Add", add);
            intent.putExtra("Single", Singleadd);
            intent.putExtra("array", array);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    singleclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
            intent.putExtra("Single", Singleadd);
            intent.putExtra("Add", add);
            intent.putExtra("array", array);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("usermoney", Counter);
    editor.putInt("Auto", add);
    editor.putInt("Single", Singleadd);
    editor.commit();
}

public int getvalue() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getInt("usermoney",0);
}

public int getaddvalue() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getInt("Auto", 0);
}

public int getSinglevalue() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getInt("Single", 0);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Counter = AutoCounter(Counter, add);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display(Counter, add);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    }, 50);
}


public int ButtonCounter(int Counter) {
    Counter += Singleadd;
    return Counter;
}

public int AutoCounter(int Counter, int add) {
    Counter = Counter + add;
    return Counter;
}

public void Display(int Counter, int add) {
    String money = String.valueOf(Counter);
    myTextView.setText(":" + money);
    myAddView.setText("$" + add + "/Per Second");

}

}
```

Thank you

Comment: show the `AndroidManifest.xml` there in lies the answer

Comment: you don't want to use shared pref. this is basically a cache call. when you reset the cache of the app, or uninstall the app, it will clear out the cache. you want to use a database.

Comment: @Blundell added Manifest

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? (Above 6.0?) https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html